# Unable to upload and image in googledrive using goolge ruby API

Tags: ruby, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-ruby-client

I am first time using Google APIs. I am unable to upload any file in Google Drive. I tried below complete code.

```
require 'google/apis/drive_v2'
require 'google/api_client/client_secrets'

# I downloaded 'client_secrets.json' file from 'https://console.developers.google.com/projectselector/apis/library' and put in lib folder

CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE = "client_secrets.json"
client_secrets_filepath = File.expand_path(CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE ,"#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/../../lib/")

 CLIENT_SECRETS = Google::APIClient::ClientSecrets.load(client_secrets_filepath)
 authorization = CLIENT_SECRETS.to_authorization

 Drive = Google::Apis::DriveV2
 @drive = Drive::DriveService.new
 @drive.authorization = authorization

file_path = File.expand_path(@ScreenShot_dir)+'/'+"imageName" +'.png'

metadata = Drive::File.new(title: 'My document')
metadata = @drive.insert_file(metadata, upload_source: file_path, content_type: 'image/png')
```

It is not uploading the file in drive but giving an error like "missing authorization code".

my client_secrets.json look like below:

```
{"installed":{
"client_id":"<some digits>.apps.googleusercontent.com",
"project_id":"<projectname>","auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
"token_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
"auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
"client_secret":"<secret key>",
"redirect_uris":["urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob","http://localhost"]}}
```

I am not sure what I am missing in it. Appreciate any help on this issue.

Comment: What is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1):

> "missing authorization code"

Means that you have not properly authenticated your code.

You should check the [Ouath2](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/ruby/guide/aaa_oauth) documentation for the client library.  Get one of the samples there working then you should be able to alter it for Drive without to much trouble.

```
# AdSense Management API command-line sample.
require 'google/apis/adsense_v1_4'
require 'google/api_client/client_secrets'
require 'google/api_client/auth/installed_app'
require 'google/api_client/auth/storage'
require 'google/api_client/auth/storages/file_store'
require 'logger'
require 'json'

CREDENTIAL_STORE_FILE = "#{$0}-oauth2.json"

# Handles authentication and loading of the API.
def setup
  log_file = File.open('adsense.log', 'a+')
  log_file.sync = true
  logger = Logger.new(log_file)
  logger.level = Logger::DEBUG

  adsense = Google::Apis::AdsenseV1_4::AdSenseService.new

  # Stores auth credentials in a file, so they survive multiple runs
  # of the application. This avoids prompting the user for authorization every
  # time the access token expires, by remembering the refresh token.
  # Note: FileStorage is not suitable for multi-user applications.
  storage = Google::APIClient::Storage.new(
    Google::APIClient::FileStore.new(CREDENTIAL_STORE_FILE))
  adsense.authorization = storage.authorize
  if storage.authorization.nil?
    client_secrets = Google::APIClient::ClientSecrets.load
    # The InstalledAppFlow is a helper class to handle the OAuth 2.0 installed
    # application flow, which ties in with Stroage to store credentials
    # between runs.
    flow = Google::APIClient::InstalledAppFlow.new(
      :client_id => client_secrets.client_id,
      :client_secret => client_secrets.client_secret,
      :scope => ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adsense.readonly']
    )
    adsense.authorization = flow.authorize(storage)
  end
  return adsense
end

# Generates a report for the default account.
def generate_report(adsense)
  report = adsense.generate_report(start_date: '2011-01-01', end_date: '2011-08-31',
                                   metric: %w(PAGE_VIEWS AD_REQUESTS AD_REQUESTS_COVERAGE
                                              CLICKS AD_REQUESTS_CTR COST_PER_CLICK
                                              AD_REQUESTS_RPM EARNINGS),
                                   dimension: %w(DATE),
                                   sort: %w(+DATE))

  # Display headers.
  report.headers.each do |header|
    print '%25s' % header.name
  end
  puts

  # Display results.
  report.rows.each do |row|
    row.each do |column|
      print '%25s' % column
    end
    puts
  end
end


if __FILE__ == $0
  adsense = setup()
  generate_report(adsense)
end
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.I have shared my complete code , can you suggest what I should change in code?